# Covert special character to html number/name and again to special character in php

Tags: php, mysql, json, special-characters

I am facing a problem with storing special characters in database and retrieving again as symbol.

For example, I have a string like `Côte d'Ivoire`

What I want to do is converting the special character `ô` to HTML number `&#244;` or name `&ocirc;` and at the time of retrieval I need to convert HTML to special symbol again.

I also need to pass this string as `JSON` response of a web service.

I tried some `php` functions like `htmlspecialchars()` and `htmlspecialchars_decode()` but not getting the desired output.

Any help will be appreciated. If there is any other way to do it then it will also be very helpful.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If that character is unicode (UTF-8), you don't need to convert it to HTML entity since unicode characters are valid in JSON format. If not, you have to convert it to unicode (UTF-8)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `htmlentities` function to transform the special characters.

You have to pass UTF8 to the `json_encode` function, so you can use `utf8_encode` on your data before encoding.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php

Comment: To revert the process there is `html_entity_decode`

Answer (score 0):

use 'utf8_unicode_ci' for Collation while saving data on database and retrieve data usual way.and check exact data is saving on database.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is much easier to solve, when you use UTF-8 for the whole site including your database. Escaping should be done as late as possible and only for the needed target system.

An example:
Your HTML page is UTF-8 encoded and you receive user input, you get the user input also in UTF-8. This value you can store as it is to the database, just use prepared statements or call `mysqli_real_escape_string()` before building the SQL-string. This escapes the input just to make it safe for SQL-statements, the database will contain the original user input.

When receiving the value back from the database you get the original UTF-8 input, then you can call `htmlspecialchars()` to escape it for displaying in HTML output. I wrote a small article about using [UTF-8 for the whole site](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/php/php.html#utf8) there you can find more information.